# How to keep the image in the input when you edit the Entity

Tags: image, symfony, entity, edit, vichuploaderbundle

I'm sure that there is something about this "problem" somewhere but I didn't found it...
I'm using Vich_Uploader bundle in my Symfony2 project. One entity has 1 reference image and a OneToMany secondary images. For the création, I've nearly no problem ( without the fact that my secondary images aren't linked to my Entity but that's not the point ) but during edit, there is nothing in the "Reference image" input and if I submit, I recieve the error : this input is required...

Someone got a tip to give the imageFile to the input?

Thanks & Regards,

Thomas

Comment: did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically fill an upload field as it would induce great security issues.
The solution to your problem would be to define your `image` fields as not required if there already are images (ie: the object is not new).

Comment: I understand for the security problem but is there a way to not show the "No file selected"? And for the "Secondary images" they say : "Please select a file" ...

Comment: Is there a way to do that?